# Why pictures taken by my app are 0 size in Android?

Tags: android, media

Pictures taken by my app, in Windows Explorer have always 0 bytes and can't be opened. I can only see them in Android Gallery app.

I am taking photo with this method :

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = PhotoUtils.createImageFile(this);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Creating image exception");
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `PhotoUtils.createImageFile(...)` :

```
public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
    String currentPhotoPath;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "ES_" + timeStamp;

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    galleryAddPic(context, currentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}

public static void galleryAddPic(Context context, String currentPhotoPath) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing the file when it is zero bytes long, in the form of your temp file. Try moving your `galleryAddPic()` call until after the picture has been taken.